# Pyramid and Chameleon ZPT

Tags: python, pyramid, chameleon, template-tal

I'm new to web development and am trying to make a simple webpage in python using Pyramid. I've run into a bit of a snag though when it comes to making template files using Chameleon. What I'm trying to do right now is very simple. The view callable returns a list of dictionaries (all dictionaries have same keys just different values). I want to put these value into a table by looping through each entry in the list.

I'm having a lot of trouble finding out how to do the loop in Chameleon. Once I have a dictionary I know how to get its values for a given key. If anyone knows of a good tutorial or can just give a quick example it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 7):

You need to use "tal:repeat".  If you've passed in "people" to the template, which is a list of dictionaries:

```
<ul>
  <li tal:repeat="person people">${person['firstname']} ${person['lastname']}</li>
</ul>
```